# Confusion over compute units and expected cores on nvidia GPU

Tags: linux, opencl, gpgpu, nvidia, pyopencl

I have an [nvidia GTX 750 Ti card](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti/specifications), which is advertised as having 640 CUDA cores. Indeed, the nvidia settings application also reports this.

I'm trying to use this card to do OpenCL development on Linux. Now, I have reported from the OpenCL environment (through PyOpenCL if it makes a difference) that the number of compute units is 5. My understanding is that one compute unit on an nvidia device maps to one multiprocessor, which I understand to be 32 SIMD units (which I assume is the a CUDA core).

Clearly, 5 * 32 is not 640 (rather a quarter of what is expected).

Am I missing something as regards the meaning of a a work unit on nvidia? The card is also driving the graphics output which will be using some of the computational capability - is a proportion of the processing capability reserved for graphics use? (if so, can I change this?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NVIDIA have a [whitepaper for the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti](http://international.download.nvidia.com/geforce-com/international/pdfs/GeForce-GTX-750-Ti-Whitepaper.pdf), which is worth a read.

An OpenCL compute unit translates to a streaming multiprocessor in NVIDIA GPU terms. Each Maxwell SMM in your GPU contains 128 processing elements ("CUDA cores") - and `128*5 = 640`. The SIMD width of the device is still 32, but each compute unit (SMM) can issue instructions to four different warps at once.

Comment: Ah very useful! So my understanding from that then is there is better sharing of resources around that pool of workers with such an architecture - the diagram shows the L1 cache etc being common to all four multiprocessors. Does this mean larger work groups are mapped across all four multiprocessors, or that multiple work groups can be run concurrently on the same SMM (with access to the same resources)? It's hard to see how to program this with OpenCL, so I imagine the former.

Comment: Both - and this has been the case for a long time (even on the old Fermi SMs with only 32 CUDA cores per SM). Scheduling multiple work-groups on the same SM is a key technique for keeping the processing elements busy whilst other work-items are waiting for data to arrive.

Comment: Right, but is it possible to code a pair of work groups such that there is benefit from both having access to the same cache? That is, so the work groups are tightly coupled.

Comment: No, that sort of resource sharing needs to happen within a work-group.

Comment: @Henry `Does this mean larger work groups are mapped across all four multiprocessors`. I suspect you meant "all four processing blocks", in which case yes, as @jprice noted. If you did mean SM, then no, work groups belong to a single SM and will live on that SM only.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly yes, I meant four processing blocks. There is so much nomenclature in this field that is vendor specific and that all means something very specific. It seems to be a case of mumble something like the right words and then explain it a lot!